# Adding border-radius for embedded YouTube video

Tags: css, youtube

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkPXj/). Notice instantly before loading the `border-radius` works fine. A few milliseconds later the rounded corners disappear.

How can I add rounded corners to embedded YouTube videos?

Comment: I'm sure it has something to do with Flash not caring about your CSS rounded corners. I'm curious if this would work with the HTML5 video element or not.

Comment: Should the video itself have rounded corners (nary impossible) or would a black container with rounded corners work?

Comment: I had this working when our site first launched. Rounded corners were working fine with YouTube videos -- until recently, maybe a few weeks ago. Suddenly, YouTube videos are behaving just how you described -- rounded container shows first, the square video pops up above it. At the same time this problem appeared, our YouTube videos stopped showing up in Firefox. Removing the border-radius code makes the videos show up fine in Firefox. Bizarre how it used to work, but doesn't now. Haven't made changes to my web pages or stylesheet. Best I can figure, it has something to do with a change that Yo

Answer (score 23):

This is very simple using CSS3. All you guys are missing out is the `z-index` which is playing bad cop.

Look at the code below, I wrapped the player in a div, set it's height and width as I like, set overflow to hidden and z-index as required. Border radius works pretty awesome!

```css
.player {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 320px;
  width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
<iframe width="480" height="320" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aiegUzPX8Zc" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this — it was the only answer that worked for me! The key was the `overflow: hidden`. `z-index` did nothing in my particular case.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `transform: scale(1)` to force it into its own layer as well.

Comment: z-index: 1 is necessary for iOS safari! That's why I came here because it was working everywhere else.

Answer (score 14):

You just have to set your `border:` styles:

```
border:20px solid #000;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/AkPXj/20/

Comment: while you are technically correct by virtue of how the question was asked, clearly it was good enough and what the question was implying. thanks for playing.

Comment: In the game of web development, there is no cheating.  If a technique yields desired results its good to go, in my opinion.  I mean, if the method sucks, no one would  use it ;--)

Comment: @albert Becuase the asker realised there was no way to achieve that result but it was closest.

Comment: well thank you for responding for him. this is almost a year old, plus your comment is over a month old. surely you have better things to do, no?

Comment: @randomblue don't see how i'm not playing nice here. but i do hope you unaccepted it to be spiteful

Comment: seriously, i never even understood why anyone downvoted my answer. that's your jsfiddle, all i did was try a style and it worked. my bad b.

Comment: so now i get 25 points back? i'd rather have clarity than points...you asked a question. i provided a solution. you provided no "rules", yet said i cheated. then told me to play nice. i'm not trying to be argumentative nor rude. you would rather have a solution adding more elements and styles to your document than one line of css? solid choice. plus my solution works in environments where you may not have control of the markup.

Comment: also did you leave out the rules of playing in your question? did you mean solve my border radius issue while playing nice? regardless, you'll have to define playing nice, because clearly our rules of webdev differ, so i'm sure our rules of playing nice differ. you asked a question. i took time out of my day to solve it. you'll see this as not playing "nice". i see this as an honest inquiry into just how ridiculous this is.

Comment: oh snap still getting love on my hated answer. werd.

Answer (score 6):

An example to get rounded corners on youtube videos or anything else, like iframes or img tags.

```
<div style="
width: 560px;
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white 100%, black 100%); /*ios 7 border-radius-bug */
-webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg); /*mac os 10.6 safari 5 border-radius-bug */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; 
overflow: hidden; 
">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZM0e1m9T9HQ" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to create the look of rounded corners, you would have to make four overlay `div`s that look like a rounded corner and position them at each corner. Not an elegant solution at all, but it's the only way to create that effect.

Comment: Why are you claiming this is the only possible way?

Comment: Containers with a border-radius don't consistently crop content contained within them, Flash content in particular. If you were to create one single div overlay, I imagine it would make it impossible to click any controls in the video, so that is why I think four absolutely-positioned corner divs are the only way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

At first the browser treats it like any other block element and applies the border radius. Then the flash object finishes loading and just goes over the top, as there is no way to use border radius on a flash object, they disappear.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. Do you think there is a way around it?

Comment: I doubt it as it's a plugin, so it can do what it likes & CSS3 isn't released yet so its not compatible with everything. You could make a wrapper div around the object which has rounded corners, but this would increase the overall size. or you could put four images at each corner on top of the object? Its not straight forward to place things on top of flash objects though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to, try a direct embed/object (best with swfobject or something) and wmode = transparent or wmode opaque (preferred)

http://jsfiddle.net/AkPXj/19/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, rounding the corners of embedded Flash videos such as YouTube and Vimeo is quite challenging due to the differences between older browsers.

If all of your end users are running a browser that supports HTML5, then just add `player=html5` to the `iframe` address like so: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/QKh1Rv0PlOQ?rel=0&player=html5`. This will force their browser to load the HTML5 version of the video, and the `border-radius` will work just fine.

---

If some of your end users' browsers *don't* support HTML5, then things start to get ugly.

Your next-most elegant solution will be something like what Ivijan-Stefan suggested, which is to address each browser individually and throw the `!important` tag on each element, possibly supplemented by adding `wmode=transparent` to the `iframe` address like so: `http://www.youtube.com/embed/QKh1Rv0PlOQ?rel=0&wmode=transparent`.

This will buy you a few extra browser versions' worth of compatibility, so you might be able to call it quits at this point.

---

For those of us that need to support a variety of legacy browsers (Internet Explorer 6, anyone?), however, the only *consistently* reliable way to do this is by making an image that looks like a curved corner, and using copies of this image to cover up each of the corners of the video. (This also requires the `wmode=transparent` trick that I described above, since some of the worst offenders will otherwise display the corner images *under* the video!)

Here is an example of this technique applied to an `iframe`-embedded YouTube video: http://jsfiddle.net/skywalkar/uyfR6/ (example radius = 20px)

> Note: If you make the corner overlays too large (greater than ~20px), then they will cover up the player controls!
>   To minimize the effects of this problem, you can try cutting the corners by rotating the images by 45 degrees. This requires a different set of overlays and some creative use of margins, but may be worth the trouble if you need larger corner radii: http://jsfiddle.net/skywalkar/BPnLh/ (example radius = 30px)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this code into your css.

```
<style>
.div-round {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.div-round::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
}

.iframe-round {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
```

And, just apply those classes into your div and iframe individually.

```
<div class="div-round" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;">
    <iframe class="iframe-round" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media; fullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xjs6fnpPWy4?modestbranding=1&autoplay=0"></iframe>
</div>
```

The final result should be displayed like this.

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible with HTML5 mode turned on for youtube player.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3f9DB/1/

Comment: What browser you testing with? This won't work with IE prior to 9th, due to absence of CSS3 and HTML5 support.

Comment: Suppose there won't be easy and stable solution other than enclosing the iframe in block element like http://jsfiddle.net/3f9DB/3/

Comment: When I run that demo (FF7), I get the Flash content.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the iframe like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xmarcos/D4sS7/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy yet very practical and useful "hack-solution" to this challenging problem.

Just embed your iframe in a "div" element like this:

```
  <div>
   <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="445" player="html5"scrolling="no" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DCTwJJhQFy8"   width="780"></iframe>
  </div>
```

then add the following css to your HTML:

```
 div {
   position: relative;
   display:inline-block;
   margin:200px;
}
div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5000;
    display: block;
    top: -27px;
    left: -27px;
    right: -27px;
    bottom: -27px;
    background-color: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 30px solid white;
    border-radius: 50px;
}][1]
```

This is quite a flexible solution, though it uses some additional layer for border-radius. This method is also compatible with most (all)  modern browsers. Hope it was useful.