# How to add border-radius to an embedded youtube video?

Tags: html, css, youtube

This is what I have so far. No matter how I add the border-radius property, it has no effect.

```
<div class="videotar_video">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/hqiNL4Hn04A" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>

    .videotar_video
    {
        border: solid white;
        border-top-width: 15px;
        border-bottom-width: 15px;
        border-left-width: 28px;
        border-right-width: 28px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
        padding-top: 5px;
        height: 0;
    }
    .videotar_video iframe
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FUBnc/

Comment: `border-radius` works on `.videotar_video` element. But the point is that you've set the color of the border to `white`. That's why you couldn't see the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/FUBnc/4/

Comment: are you asking how to add it to the embedded video, or as all the answers suggest; to the border around it?

Comment: ok, here: http://jsfiddle.net/FUBnc/6/ the video itself isnt bordered

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding border-radius for embedded YouTube video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811719/adding-border-radius-for-embedded-youtube-video)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
.videotar_video
{
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-top-width: 15px;
border-bottom-width: 15px;
border-left-width: 28px;
border-right-width: 28px;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 5px;
height: 0;
marging: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #000000
}
.videotar_video iframe
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Vqp3/

Comment: eeek, let me think about it, its a little bit cheat :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Border-radius in your css

```
.videotar_video
    {
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: It works.videotar_video
{
    border: solid red;
    border-top-width: 15px;
    border-bottom-width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 28px;
    border-right-width: 28px;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
 padding-top: 5px;
 height: 0;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px !important;
    
}

Comment: change the color of your border to red you can see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Small but beautiful trick.

```
iframe,
object,
embed{
    border:5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px !important; 
    -ms-border-radius: 20px !important; 
    -o-border-radius: 20px !important;  
    border-radius: 20px !important;     
}
```

**[DEMO](https://creativform.makes.org/thimble/MTE5NDMyODMyMA==/how-to-add-border-radius-on-embedded-youtube-video)**