# How can I add border-radius to a video in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, video, styling, border-radius

How can I add `border-radius` to the `<video>` tag.
This is what my video looks like right now:

(image is here: <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/izKz0.png")

I already tried doing the video tag with css but it doesn't change.

Here is the code:

```css
/*CSS*/

video {
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!HTML!>

<div class="fp-player">
<center>
<div id="instructions">
  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="320" height="240"
      controls preload="none" data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }' poster="https://example.org/image.png">
    <source src="https://example.org/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>
  </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like the border radius is applied just fine in the snippet you posted

Comment: @irowe Maybe it's just my browser.

Comment: Because I am using safari, and I haven't updated to the latest version.

Comment: What are you using? I've got Chrome 83 on MacOS and I can see the rounded corners in the snippet preview. It becomes a lot more obvious if I crank the border-radius up to 100px

Comment: I am on Safari On MacOS Catalina

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#Broswer_compatibility

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rounded corners on html5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238451/rounded-corners-on-html5-video)

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238451/rounded-corners-on-html5-video, although an answer below also points out that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811719/adding-border-radius-for-embedded-youtube-video/7941820 could help you

Comment: This might also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037784/html5-video-border-radius-in-chrome-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the video in a div and give it this styling,

```
div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 320px;
  width: 480px;
}
```

I found this answer at [Adding border-radius for embedded YouTube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811719/adding-border-radius-for-embedded-youtube-video/7941820)

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing your browsing history.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that may help

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<style>

#video1 {
border-radius:10px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="320" height="240" controls preload="none">
    <source src="https://example.org/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Add "border-radius:10px;" to the style of the video.